# Cruise Control and Mercurial. Setup problems

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I am completely a newbie in continuous integration but I am trying to learn it.

Here is my set up.

I have a main production location. Computer A.
I have a virtual machine hosting Windows Server 2008 OS which have Cruise Control.NET installed and running. Computer B
I use Mercurial as my source control tool installed in Computer A.

Everything is configured and I can see Cruise Control report on my Computer B Web server and I can me my repository on Computer A Web server.

The problem is the following :

From my Computer B's  Cruise Control console I have the following error :

Source control failure  :
Unable to execute file [c:\develop\CCnet\WorkingDir\hg]. The file may not exist or may not be executable.
File not found 'C:\develop\CCnet\CCnetrtifacts\msbuils-results.xml.

What I did is that I copied my project directory on the Cruise Control computer  c:\develop\CCnet\WorkingDir\

and Here is my source control block included in my ccnet.config :

```
<sourcecontrol type="hg">
<repo>http://mylocalmachinewebserver<repo>
<workingDirectory>c:\develop\CCnet\WorkingDirectory<workingDirectory>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Could someone help me understand my problem

Many thanks

Comment: is mercurial actually installed in your workingdirectory? that seems weird to me. I would run something like .\hg status from there and see if you get any output other than "cmd not found" etc...

Comment: No Mercurial is installed in my production location not my server Continuous Integration location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is mercurial in your path?  It's possible that the user under which cruise control is running has a different path than does your normal user. Is it possible to provide the full path to hg in the cruisecontrol config?

Comment: What would be the full path ? The path that I have included in the config file is the web server address where the repository is. Is there a specific path where a specific file must be present ?

Comment: The full path to the exectutable.  'hg' is a program on your cruise control running computer in a folder, and the full path to it depends on where you installed it.  Something like "C:\Program Files\some\thing\hg.exe" I image.  CruiseControl is failing to find it, probably due to your %PATH% setting for the CC user.

Have you considered using Hudson?  It's _much_ better than CC.

Comment: There also is an `<executable>` element that you can use in your `<sourcecontrol>` to point to the path to your hg.exe